# Onclick chamando função javascript apaga o textbox htm

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tenho um controle  text *HTML* que é criado por uma função chamada no `OnClientClick` do botão. O problema que toda vez que eu adiciono um novo `Textbox`, os dados do anterior se apagam.

O que fazer para que ele não se apague?

Obs: Como estou criando via *HTML*, não poderei criar `asp:UpdatePanel`!

Função Javascript

```
function novo() {

        var form, quant;

        if (parseInt(i) < 51) {
            form = "<table width='96%' border='0'><tr><td width='8%' class='tblNormal' align='Right'>CPF:</td>"
            form = form + "<td width='12%' class='tblNormal'> <input type='text' onkeypress='FiltraTecla(event);' id='cpf" + i + "' value='' size='10' maxlength='10' onblur='valorDoCampo(this.value, " + i + ")'> "
            form = form + "</tr></table>"

            document.getElementById('<% =qtd.ClientID %>').value = i;

            i = i + 1;
            formularios.innerHTML = formularios.innerHTML + form + "<br>";

        }
        else {
            alert("Numero máximo excedido.");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: poste as outras partes relevantes do código por favor

Comment: Me parece que o problema pode estar na função valorDoCampo(), chamada no onBlur do input. Se tiver como postar função, fica mais fácil dizer.

Comment: Como voce esta usando asp.net, depois de executar sua funcao voce precisa dar um return false no OnClientClick, se vai acontecer um post no form. Como esse valor nao existe no ViewState da pagina é apagado.

Answer (score 1):

o `innerHTML` é o que está apagando o conteúdo dos `Textbox` anteriores.
Em vez de `innerHTML`, use [`appendChild`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp):

```
function novo() {
    var form, quant;

    if (parseInt(i) < 51) {
        form = document.createElement('table')
        form.setAttribute('width', '96%');
        form.setAttribute('border', '0');
        form.innerHTML = "<tr><td width='8%' class='tblNormal' align='Right'>CPF:</td>";
        form.innerHTML+= "<td width='12%' class='tblNormal'> <input type='text' onkeypress='FiltraTecla(event);' id='cpf" + i + "' value='' size='10' maxlength='10' onblur='valorDoCampo(this.value, " + i + ")'> ";
        form.innerHTML+= "</tr>";

        document.getElementById('<% =qtd.ClientID %>').value = i;

        i = i + 1;
        formularios.appendChild(form); // adiciona o formulario
        formularios.appendchild(document.createElement('br')) // adiciona nova linha

    }
    else {
        alert("Numero máximo excedido.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, se você usar JQuery, você pode usar um código desta forma:

```
function novo() {

        var form, quant;

        if (parseInt(i) < 51) {
            form = "<table width='96%' border='0'><tr><td width='8%' class='tblNormal' align='Right'>CPF:</td>"
            form = form + "<td width='12%' class='tblNormal'> <input type='text' onkeypress='FiltraTecla(event);' id='cpf" + i + "' value='' size='10' maxlength='10' onblur='valorDoCampo(this.value, " + i + ")'> "
            form = form + "</tr></table>"

            document.getElementById('<% =qtd.ClientID %>').value = i;

            i++;
            formularios.append(form);

        }
        else {
            alert("Numero máximo excedido.");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Creio q o erro n seja por isso.